# Load png as sprite java

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel

First, I'm sorry for my bad English.
I know that my question is similar, maybe same as other people's, many poeple's question out there on internet.but I've tried many of them, but sill dont work. The simple is i dont know my fault.

here's the cronology :

I have 5 class, they're Game.java, Player.java, Menu.java, System.java, and Control.java.
the Control class is a KeyListener class, so thats for controlling from keyboard.
System class is the main class, to show the JFrame.
Menu class is for menu, which show background and button. It has *extends JPanel*.
Player class, of course for Player statistic.
Game.java, is the heart of my project, because it control the gameplay.

So, how I load my player's png. My structure is System call Menu, then Menu call Game(new game button), so then Game call Player class. But as I click *new game* button or press *enter*, there's nothing happen, the others is fine(loading background, exit button).

System.java

```
public class System extends JFrame{
private final int lebar=954;
private final int tinggi=540;

private static boolean[] kibod = new boolean[525];

public System(){
    this.setTitle("Unknown man Unkown power");
    this.setSize(new Dimension(lebar,tinggi));
    this.setFocusable(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setContentPane(new Menu());
    this.addKeyListener(new Control());
    this.setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new Sistem();
        }
    });
}

}
```

Menu.java

```
public class Menu extends JPanel{
 private int l=954;
private int t=540;

JButton menu1=new JButton("MULAI BARU");
JButton menu2=new JButton("KELUARRR");

public Menu(){
    this.add(menu1);
    this.add(menu2);

    menu1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            new Game();
        }
    });
    menu2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

}
}
```

Player.java

```
public class Player extends JPanel{
private int posx=System.WIDTH/3;
private int posy=System.HEIGHT/3;

private BufferedImage im;
private Graphics gr;

public void loadl() {
    try {
        im=ImageIO.read(new File("res/glakon2.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    gr=g;
    g.drawImage(im, posx, posy, System.WIDTH/3, System.HEIGHT/3, this);
}
public Player(){
    loadl();
}
}
```

Game.java

```
public class Game{

public Game() {

    new Player();
}
}
```

Game class is still empty, as for I just want to test it showing or not. I've tried loading png with

```
URL u=this.getClass().getResource("res/glakon2.png");
im=ImageIO.read(u);
```

or

```
im=ImageIO.read(new File("res/glakon2.png"));
```

My png are a spritesheet png, contains only 2 image. So how I load it?
Thank you for attention and help.

Sorry, I've edited Game.java to match the question, the real things is its Gameplay.java.

Comment: Where is the image located?

Comment: try `.getResource("/res/glakon2.png");`. Added extra `/`. Your file `res` should be directly a child of `src`

Comment: on 'res' folder, as I've set 'res' in buld path

Comment: @peeskillet it still wont work, I've just tried it

Comment: try .getResource("C:/..../res/glakon2.png"); the complete path for image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I use the below setup it works fine

```
new ImageIcon(TestIMage.class.getResource("/res/stackoverflow5.png"));
```

[image]

```
package stackoverflow;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TestIMage {

    public TestIMage() {
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(TestIMage.class.getResource("/res/stackoverflow5.png"));
        JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(label);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TestIMage();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

Also I think a problem you are facing is not having a preffered sise of the panel. You should @Override the `getPreferredSize()` of the panel. Something like this.

```
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(DIM_W, DIM_H);
    }
```

Also you should override the `paintComponent` method and calling `super.paintComponent`, instead of `paint`,  like this

```
   @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        gr = g;
        g.drawImage(im, 0, 0, DIM_W, DIM_W, this);
    }
```

Run this test. I used your `Player` class

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestIMage {

    public TestIMage() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new Player());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TestIMage();
            }
        });
    }

    private class Player extends JPanel {

        private  int DIM_W;
        private  int DIM_H;

        private BufferedImage im;
        private Graphics gr;

        public void loadl() {
            try {
                im = ImageIO.read(TestIMage.class.getResource("/res/stackoverflow5.png"));
                DIM_W = im.getWidth();
                DIM_H = im.getHeight();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(DIM_W, DIM_H);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            gr = g;
            g.drawImage(im, 0, 0, DIM_W, DIM_W, this);
        }

        public Player() {
            loadl();
        }
    }
}
```

---

### UPDATE

Also you need to make sure you add the `Player` to a top level container like a `JDialog`. Currently in your `Game` class, all you do is create in instance of the `Player` class, but you never add the `Player` to a container. If you want to use a `JDialog` you can do that with your `Game` class

```
class Game extends JDialog {
    public Game(JFrame frame, boolean modal) {
        super(frame, modal);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new Player());

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The in your `actionPerformed` you can do this

```
menu1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        new Game(System.this, true);
    }
});
```

---

### UPDATE 2

> ":) it works, I've make test class, and call it through System class, but if I call it from Game class, it won't appear. And about JDialog, is it create another JFrame? I think its simple with only one JFrame(its declared in System class)"

I'm not sure about the flow of your program. I don't know what you attempting to do with `Game` class. If you want the `Player` to be in the main frame, then you have to `.add` if the the frame. You can't do that with `Game` class because a `Game` class is not a component. You can use a `CardLayout` though, if you want to show the `Player` screen when a button is pressed.

Here's an example

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestIMage {
    private Player player = new Player();
    private JPanel introPanel = new JPanel();
    private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    private JButton button = new JButton("View Player");
    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(cardLayout);

    public TestIMage() {
        introPanel.setPreferredSize(player.getPreferredSize());
        introPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        introPanel.add(button);

        mainPanel.add(introPanel, "introPanel");
        mainPanel.add(player, "playerPanel");

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cardLayout.show(mainPanel, "playerPanel");
            }
        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TestIMage();
            }
        });
    }

    private class Player extends JPanel {


        private  int DIM_W;
        private  int DIM_H;

        private BufferedImage im;
        private Graphics gr;

        public void loadl() {
            try {
                im = ImageIO.read(TestIMage.class.getResource("/res/stackoverflow5.png"));
                DIM_W = im.getWidth();
                DIM_H = im.getHeight();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(DIM_W, DIM_H);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            gr = g;
            g.drawImage(im, 0, 0, DIM_W, DIM_W, this);
        }

        public Player() {
            loadl();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: its still won't work, I've use 'ImageIcon' and add 'JLabel' in Player.java, it still shows error. the error is _Exception_in_thread_"AWT-EventQueue-0"_java.lang.NullPointerException_

Comment: See my **EDIT**. I think it's a problem with the preferred size

Comment: I use _BufferedImage_ as _Player_ loader in my game project, can _ImageIcon_ being the controllable object? like moving?

Comment: You should use `BufferedImage` if you are painting. Not an `ImageIcon`. I was just using a quick example without having to paint. But I used your class in my **EDIT** and it also works fine

Comment: Also you have to remember to actually `add` and instance of your `Player` panel to a container. Your `Game` class doesn't do anything when you just instantiate `Player`

Comment: sorry for late comment, its . . . . still won't work :)
it shows input error : _Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)_
I'm still confused, why you can but I cant, even with my own code?

Comment: Look at my file structure in the image. Is that how you have it? With `res` directly in `src`?

Comment: Make sure you're using `Player.class.getResource("/res/glakon2.png");` and make sure your `res` is directly in the `src`

Comment: :) it works, I've make _test_ class, and call it through System class, but if I call it from Game class, it won't appear. And about JDialog, is it create another JFrame? I think its simple with only one JFrame(its declared in _System_ class)

Comment: I'm not sure about the flow of your program. I don't know what you attempting to do with `Game` class. If you want the `Player` to be in the main frame, then you have to `.add` if the the frame. You can't do that with `Game` class because a `Game` class is not a component. You can use a `CardLayout` though, if you want to show the `Player` screen when a button is pressed.

Comment: my flow is System call Menu, then Menu call Game(new game button), so then Game call Player class, as I described on my question. Yes, i think I should use _CardLayout_, I'll try it.

Comment: is _TestImage_ similar to _System_ class, or _Game_, or _Menu_?

Comment: You could do it in your `Menu` class since your `System` only adds the `Menu` class. You don't need the `Game` class at all.

Comment: But I though that _Game_ class is use to control the game, like loading player, enemy, environment, etc. Thats why I call _Player_ from it. So Game is the framework. The _Menu_ job is only call _Game_ and exit

Comment: You do realize this site is not help desk right? It's a Question and Answer site. You ask one question, you get it answered, then you move on. No one is here to help you develop your entire program.

Comment: NO, thats not what I mean, ok, sorry if my confusiation is bothering you, I'll do it on my own.
you've helped me solve loading png after all. thanks

Comment: I apologize for my earlier statement. It's frustrating when someone expects you to know what they're talking about when there wasn't any previous context mentioned.

Comment: thats nothing, no problem
:)